# Insert and echo elements in multidimensional session array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a multidimensional array for a php session. Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    // store session data

    $products = array();
    $_SESSION['Products'] = $products;

    $products[]= array("Brand"=>$_POST['Brand']);

    //retrieve session data
    echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products'][$products][0]["Brand"];

    echo "Product Name = ". $products[0]["Brand"];

    ?>
```

`$_POST['Brand']` can be anything like `"Adidas"`

What I would like is something like this:

```
Array Session 'Products'

   Array '$products'

     Sub-Array 'array'
           (
               "Brand" => "Adidas"
           )

     Sub-Array 'array'
           (
               "Brand" => "Nike"
           )

     Sub-Array 'array'
           (
               "Brand" => "Puma"
           )
```

and so on.

Right now `echo "Product Name = ". $products[0]["Brand"];` gives me `Product Name = Adidas`

but `echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products'][$products][0]["Brand"];` just gives me `Product Name =`

My question is, what is the right way to echo the data from a multidimensional array in my case?

Thanks

**Edited**

Okay I've modified my code to this:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Products']= array("Brand"=>"Adidas");

    echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products']["Brand"];
    ?>
```

If I only do this then it prints `Product Name = Adidas`

However if I do this:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Products']= array("Brand"=>"Adidas");
    $_SESSION['Products']= array("Brand"=>"Puma");

    echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products'][0]["Brand"];
    echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products'][1]["Brand"];
    ?>
```

Then again no luck. In theory shouldn't this work though?

Comment: Debug with `print_r($_SESSION)`. You will see the structure.  You should not do `$_SESSION['Products'] = $products;` _before_ you have populated the array `$products`. Do it after, as arrays are not assigned by reference in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Change the order of assignings**

```
$products[] = array("Brand"=>$_POST['Brand']);
$_SESSION['Products'] = $products;
```

instead of

```
$products[] = array("Brand"=>$_POST['Brand']);
$_SESSION['Products'] = $products;
```

**2) Correct your session variable**

```
$_SESSION['Products'][0]["Brand"]
```

instead of

```
$_SESSION['Products'][$products][0]["Brand"]
```

***UPDATE**:* Here is solution for your updated question:

```
$_SESSION['Products'][] = array("Brand"=>"Adidas");
$_SESSION['Products'][] = array("Brand"=>"Puma");

echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products'][0]["Brand"];
echo "Product Name = ". $_SESSION['Products'][1]["Brand"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the order of these two statements:

```
$_SESSION['Products'] = $products;

$products[]= array("Brand"=>$_POST['Brand']);
```

Now you are assigning an empty array to `$_SESSION['Products']` and that will not get updated as you add values to your `$products` variable.

So:

```
$products[]= array("Brand"=>$_POST['Brand']);

$_SESSION['Products'] = $products;
```